# How to pass parameters to report model in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, model, report, rdl

I'm developing report in RS that show top N customers based on some criteria. It also allows to select number of customers and period of time.

Is it possible to do it by using report model? Thing that it seems to be difficult is how to pass parameters determined by user.

Another thing that in my oppinion is very disappointing is that i cannot use SQL query as dataset query, because it uses odd and elaborate XML. Although report model items seem to map its fields to query or table fields.

I m concerning using report models because i need to provide uniform data model (the same tables and fields) for more or less different database schemas.

It would be very nice if somebody would explain what can be done with report models and what can not.

Comment: This is a *very* generic question.  Can you be a little more specific?  Do you need guidance on how to develop SQL reports?

Comment: As I said I need to know how to create report showing top N customers that uses as a data source report model instead of SQL query. User sets period of time and number of positions and then clicks [View Report] (those are report parameters). 

To be clear I dont want to fetch all client records to report server where appropriate filters would be applied. Instead of that  report server should create query to database (respecting user criteria) which basically should be an equivalent of query i would write when not using report model.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is to use the result of a Stored Procedure as the data source for your report. You would need to define parameters at a Dataset level to pass to the SP

Answer (score 1):

You can create report model based paramaterized filters through the query designer by adding a filter, drag the field you want to filter on into the filter area, then right click on it and select "Prompt".  This will automatically create a report parameter which you can then edit via the parameter properties dialog to set the data type, allow multiple values, etc.